# OLS Duplicated Feature

Tags: regression, least-squares, multicollinearity

Let's say we have $n$ samples and a single feature variable $X$, and we run OLS to regress $Y$ onto $X$ and get some $\beta$. Now, suppose we duplicate this feature to now get $X_1=X_2$, and we regress $Y$ onto $X_1, X_2$ to get coefficients $\beta_1, \beta_2$- how are our OLS coefficients and standard errors going to change, and how do we analytically prove this?

Intuitively, I know that $\beta=\beta_1+\beta_2,$ but from running statsmodels, why exactly do we get $\beta_1=\beta_2=\frac{1}{2}\beta$? Is this just a implementation thing? Also, why would our t-stats for $\beta_1, \beta_2$ be halved? Intuitively I'd think there would be more variance, since our betas can take on any value as long as they sum to $\beta$.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are doing, this regression cannot be run due to multicollinearity.